# Force Password Expiration

Tags: security

I used [this](https://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/06/08/enforce-password-expiration-in-the-sitecore-cms/) before Sitecore 8 to force users to reset their passwords if they are past a certain date. I've been given this task again in Sitecore 8. It looks like the new change password page requires user authentication meaning I cannot invalidate their login. 
The aspx page I am referring to is located at the following location: `webroot/sitecore/shell/Applications/Security/ChangePassword/changepassword.aspx`. Is there a different page I should redirect the user?

If not is there a pipeline that I could add a processor to other than `httprequestbegin` that will do the following:

1. If a user is logged in with an expired password redirect them to the change password page (unless the current requested page is the change password page)
2. If page mode is preview mode and the underlying user has an expired password redirect them to the change password page (unless the current requested page is the change password page)

Preview mode seems to be a special case because the context user is `extranet\anonymous` so I'm not sure if there's a way to fix up that issue. It's such an edge case anyway. The user following this path would need a url to access preview mode but I would like to cover this if possible.

Using: Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 170614)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a good way to keep a user who logged in from seeing the preview page. With that being said, here's what I ended up doing:

```
public class RedirectUserToChangedPassword : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    private TimeSpan TimeSpanToExpirePassword { get; set; }
    private string ChangePasswordPageUrl { get; set; }

    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (((Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal || Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPreview)
                && Sitecore.Context.Site != null
                //custom method: IsContentSite
                && Sitecore.Context.Site.IsContentSite())
            || Sitecore.Context.User == null
            || Sitecore.Context.User.IsAdministrator
            || args.Url == null
            || String.Equals(args.Url.FilePath, ChangePasswordPageUrl, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return;

        var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(Sitecore.Context.User.Name, false);

        if (!HasPasswordExpired(membershipUser))
            return;

        var queryString = new NameValueCollection();
        queryString.Add(Constants.Sitecore.ChangePassword.OriginalUrlKey, args.Url.FilePathWithQueryString);

        //custom method: ToQueryString
        WebUtil.Redirect(ChangePasswordPageUrl + (ChangePasswordPageUrl.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + queryString.ToQueryString());
    }

    private bool HasPasswordExpired(MembershipUser user)
    {
        return user.LastPasswordChangedDate.Add(TimeSpanToExpirePassword) <= DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Patch:

```
  <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
      <pipelines>
        <httpRequestBegin>
          <processor type="MyDll.CustomSitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.RedirectUserToChangedPassword, MyDll"
                     patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.UserResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']">
            <TimeSpanToExpirePassword>00:00:01:00</TimeSpanToExpirePassword>
            <ChangePasswordPageUrl>/sitecore/shell/Applications/Security/ChangePassword/customchangepassword.aspx</ChangePasswordPageUrl>
          </processor>
        </httpRequestBegin>
      </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
  </configuration>
```

From the config you can see that I created a custom change password page. I copied the default one into my project with a new name and had it inherit my own source. The reason I had to do this is that normally this aspx opens in a dialog. After hitting the continue button it is, by default, set up to close the top dialog. Here is my class that `customchangepassword.aspx` used:

```
public class ChangePasswordPage : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.ChangePassword.ChangePasswordPage
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        ChangePassword.ContinueButtonClick += ChangePassword_ContinueButtonClick;
    }

    private void ChangePassword_ContinueButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(sender, "sender");
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(e, "e");

        var originalUrl = Request.QueryString[Constants.Sitecore.ChangePassword.OriginalUrlKey];
        if (!originalUrl.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            WebUtil.Redirect(originalUrl);
        }
        else if (Sitecore.Context.User != null)
        {
            WebUtil.Redirect(Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.StartUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            WebUtil.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }
    }
}
```

I kept the original contents of `changepassword.aspx` the same other than the very top line. I changed the top line of `changepassword.aspx` to the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="Namespace.To.Custom.Code.ChangePasswordPage" MasterPageFile="~/sitecore/shell/DialogPage.Master" CodeBehind="ChangePassword.aspx.cs" %>
```

`Constants.Sitecore.ChangePassword.OriginalUrlKey` was in a constant file and had a value of `originalUrl`.

Comment: what is the value in Constants.Sitecore.ChangePassword.OriginalUrlKey and can you please add the code in customchangepassword.aspx page also?

Comment: @Anjo I updated my answer. Let me know if there are any other questions.