# Custom change password page for Sitecore 8.1 - Password expiration

Tags: sitecore-client, login

I am trying to customize password expiration in Sitecore 8.1.

As mentioned in  [this article](https://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/06/08/enforce-password-expiration-in-the-sitecore-cms/) I have added a pipeline before the LogingIn pipeline to check whether the time span for password expiration has exceeded for the user and if exceeded the user is navigated to `changepassword.aspx` page.
In Sitecore 8.2 change password opens as a dialog which is available in `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Security/ChangePassword/changepassword.aspx`.
 As per this [Sitecore beta question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7647/force-password-expiration) I tried to create a custom `changepassword.aspx` by copying from original page and placing it in `sitecore/login/`
I changed the `login` site definition to include `loginPage` property (ex: `<site name="login" ... loginPage="/sitecore/login" />`)

When I click the Login button on the home screen instead of getting redirected to `changepassword.aspx` page, it's loading the same page with `returnUrl=%2Fsitecore%2Flogin%2Fcustomchangepassword.aspx` appended to the URL as a query string.
Please suggest a way to redirect to `customchangepassword.aspx`.

Answer (score 1):

The change password page is no longer available to an anonymous user. Because of that choosing to not log the user in like the linked article will not work without removing the restriction to that page. Removing that restriction will not actually work since it requires a logged in user to get who to change the password for. The new change password form has current password, changed password, and confirm changed password fields so there's no way to choose a username from that. You can create a custom form like the old version however I believe Sitecore probably did this for a security reason so I wouldn't go that route and would instead follow [the question you linked](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7647/force-password-expiration). You would need to remove the code from the linked article which does not let the user log in.